# Why function similarity return 1 while 2 value not the same?

Tags: postgresql

Value in databbase: `fullname="This is a pen."`

My query: `SELECT SIMILARITY(fullname,'This is a a pen') as sl from users`

Result: `sl=1`

Why function similarity  return 1 while 2 value not the same?

How can return 1 when value is the same. If value not the same return < 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the period is stripped from the string when trigrams are created. Also, if a trigram occurs more than once (like from your `' a a '`, these duplicates are ignored:

```
SELECT show_trgm('This is a a pen.');

                                 show_trgm                                 
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 {"  a","  i","  p","  t"," a "," is"," pe"," th","en ",his,"is ",pen,thi}
(1 row)
```

To test for equality, use the `=` operator. Perhaps something like this will satisfy:

```
ORDER BY fullname = 'This is a a pen' DESC,
         similarity(fullname, 'This is a a pen') DESC
```

Comment: is [a a pen]  vs [a pen] stripped ?

Comment: Not stripped; but `similarity` counts unique trigrams. Using `similarity` there is no difference between "This is a pen" and "This pen is a is a a a a a a pen pen pen", because the same set of trigrams appear in both. Maybe `levenshtein` might fit your use case better.

Comment: Oops, I didn't even see the duplicated "a". Answer improved.

Comment: Thank you. levenshtein is better in my case. i will find a way to convert levenshtein to percentage.